# Whay does mean "= keyof Events" in this interface "interface PublicEmitter<Events, Key extends keyof Events = keyof Events>{ ... }"

Tags: typescript

I know what is `keyof Events` or `Key extends keyof Events`. But what does `= keyof Event` here?

```
interface PublicEmitter<Events, Key extends keyof Events = keyof Events>{ // ... }
```

I learn this example of typescript code:

https://github.com/sergeysova/emitting/blob/master/src/index.ts#L12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `= keyof Event` is a default type for the type parameter. This means that if no type parameter is specified for that type parameter, the default is used. So `PublicEmitter<any>` is equivalent to `PublicEmitter<any, keyof Events>`. Without the default `PublicEmitter<any>` would be a compiler error since not all type parameters are specified.